# I need to find or create an app for GoogleTV or FireTV that can display Canon CR2 RAW image files

Tags: image-viewer

I'm a serious amateur photographer with a 120K+ digital image library going back 20 years. I want to be able to display these images on a TV using either GoogleTV (the TV's native OS) or a FireStick that's plugged into the TV. Most of the images are in Canon's CR2 RAW format, and I can't seem to find an app that can read or display CR2 images. Does anyone know if one exists? I have a basic programming background, so as a fall back I could attempt to create one, or perhaps add an existing library to VLC (which works great already on GTV/FS, just no RAW support). I'd love any pointers that anyone can share on directions I can pursue here!

Comment: Bumping this up for some hopeful visibility to someone that may have pointers for me? Thanks in advance!